# How to print to the terminal in this Haskell code?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get a simulation running with Gloss in Haskell.

I tried writing a simple script where I want to print "Clicked!" to the terminal every time I click anywhere on the Gloss canvas. The world I pass to the Gloss' play function, is an IO action so I can enable printing to the terminal in response to events.

However, nothing prints to the terminal! :-(

```
module Main where
import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game
import System.IO.Unsafe

data World  = World { test :: String
                   } deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
          let initialioWorld   = return World{test=""} :: IO World
          let windowSize      = (1800,1800)
          let windowPosition  = (0,0)
          let backgroundColor = orange
          let framesPerSecond = 20
          play (InWindow "" windowSize windowPosition) backgroundColor framesPerSecond
                initialioWorld ( const Blank ) handleEvent  (const id)


handleEvent :: Event -> IO World  -> IO World
handleEvent event ioworld

 | (EventKey (MouseButton LeftButton) Down _ (x,y)) <- event,
               World str <- unsafePerformIO ioworld
   = do
       putStrLn "Clicked!"
       return (World str)

 | otherwise = ioworld
```

Now I understand, what Haskell is probably doing is just *evaluating* that IO action and NOT *executing* it, and that this has something to do with Haskell's laziness.

So how do I force printing to the terminal in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the pure version of `play`.  If you want to do IO in the event handler, you must use `Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Game.playIO`.  With that, the event handler has type

```
Event -> world -> IO world
```

Which takes a pure `world`, and returns an `IO` action that will be executed.

Note that this will also require your drawing and step functions to return `IO` actions as well (`(return . const Blank)`, and `(return . const id)` respectively).  Also, you must no longer `return` your initial world into `IO`.

Comment: Oh wow!!! This worked perfectly. Thank you so much! Just to be sure, I can do arbitrary IO with this function right??, i..e writing / reading from files etc. I mean we are not restricted to printing to the terminal?

Comment: @smilingbuddha You *can* but remember that you have little control over how the callback function is called. If you need to actually manage real resources inside your game (not just printing to stdout) you should do so within a thread started outside of the gloss runtime.